# Unable to use webbrowser.open in python / SimpleCV on Arch

Tags: python, archlinux, simplecv

I'm working on a simple CV project making use of [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/) on [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/). Displaying images and feeds through the repl in individual windows works fine, however using a browser for displaying does not work.

```
img.show()
```

Works.

```
img.show(type="browser")
```

Does not work. The repl shows the following message:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html.py:14: ShimWarning: The
>   `IPython.html` package has been deprecated. You should import from
>   `notebook` instead. `IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`. 
>   "`IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`.", ShimWarning)

[Stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/M8EECAgY) on pastebin.

Strangely enough the same works just fine on [Debian](https://www.debian.org/), so I assume there might be a version issue involved.

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the ShimWarning you have is not the problem (yet, at least). The stacktrace shows an exception in the python imaging library (PIL): `Exception: fromstring() has been removed. Please call frombytes() instead.`

So I suspect you are right about a version mismatch. It looks like Arch Linux is on [python-pil 3.1](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/python2-pillow/) while Debian stable is still on [python-pil 2.6](https://packages.debian.org/stable/python-pil) which still has the `fromstring` method.

You might be able to force the PIL version by running `pip install pillow==2.6.2` from the command line before you run IPython.

Comment: Getting "install: missing destination file operand after 'pillow==2.6.2'"

Comment: I have resorted to setting up a Debian VM for development - thanks anyway!